# wxPython proper way to align widgets

Tags: wxpython, alignment, wxwidgets

I want my StaticTexts and TextCtrls to be aligned like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/llE7F.png

so I did this:

```
import wx

class LoginForm(wx.Frame):
 def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,wx.ID_ANY,title='Login',size=(800,600))

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)

    email_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,'Email: ')
    pass_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,'Password: ')

    email = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,'',size=(150,-1))
    passwd = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,'',size=(150,-1))

    loginBtn = wx.Button(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,'Login')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onLogin,loginBtn)

    topSizer =   wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    labelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    inputSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    labelSizer.Add(email_label,0,wx.RIGHT,112)
    labelSizer.Add(pass_label,0,wx.RIGHT,177)

    inputSizer.Add(email,0,wx.RIGHT,5)
    inputSizer.Add(passwd,0,wx.RIGHT,5)
    inputSizer.Add(loginBtn,0,wx.RIGHT,10)

    topSizer.Add(labelSizer,0,wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT,0)
    topSizer.Add(inputSizer,0,wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT,0)

    self.panel.SetSizer(topSizer)

 def onLogin(self):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
app = wx.App()
frame = LoginForm().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Is this the proper way? To play around with align flags and border values? Or there's another way to do this?

The way that I did it, if I want to change, for example, the width of login button, everything will be messed up

Answer (score 0):

No, you should never be using the border to do any kind of alignment, this is guaranteed to break on the other platforms or even the same platform with a different font.

I am not sure what is the problem with your desired layout, to be honest, it seems to be pretty trivial to implement by just putting two identical vertical box sizers containing a label and a text inside a horizontal box sizer (alternatively, you could use a `wxFlexGridSizer`). Perhaps you should clarify what exactly made you use pixel values in the borders.

Comment: Well, it's my first time working with wxPython.
I have two horizontal sizers because I want the StaticTexts to be on a raw, and TextCtrls on the next raw. If I had understood what you said, I can use wxFlexGridSizer instead of those horizontal sizers. It's something like a HTML table used for page layout? If so, can I align "email:" above the TextCtrl box using this type of sizers?

Answer (score 0):

Use GridSizer for a layout like that.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(450, 250))
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        gs = wx.GridSizer(4, 4, 1, 1)

        gs.AddMany( [
            (wx.StaticText(self), wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(self), wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(self, label='Email'), 0, wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(self, label='Password'), 0, wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(self), wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(self), wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.TextCtrl(self), 0, ),
            (wx.TextCtrl(self), 0, ),
             ])

        vbox.Add(gs)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Login')
    app.MainLoop()
```